# Adding Parameters giving error - must declare the scalar variable "@variable"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using the following code to try to return results from a SQL Server database table

```
 MySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE [My Id] = @variable";
 MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@variable", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GetsMyId(this.Mycombobox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

I've tried using .Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable",value); but I've read about the drawbacks and decided to use this method instead. The code works with neither. Returning the error ' Must declare the scalar variable "@variable"'

I'm not sure what I'm missing since I have a working version that achieves something similar. In this case the context is different however, with this code following the original

```
//Line that fixes it (added at this point) for anyone else that encounters the issue.
//MySqlConnection.connection = MyConnection;

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(MySqlCommand.CommandText, conn.ConnectionString);

DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();

Adapter.Fill(MyDataTable);
```

With the error being thrown at the final line `Adapter.Fill(MyDataTable)`

Is there something silly I've missed or is there some incompatibility I'm not aware of betweeen Adding parameter values and DataAdapters?

Comment: If `GetsMyId` can return a null value then you will get this error.  You need to make sure parameters have a non-null value.  you can use `DBNull.Value` in place of `null` in C# to represent a null value in SQL.

Comment: GetsMyId is declared as a private int Method so as far as I'm aware it cannot return a null value?

Comment: What `GetsMyId(this.Mycombobox.SelectedItem.ToString())` returns exactly? Did you debug your code and see it? Also you try to mean `..Add("@variable", SqlDbType.Int).Value..` instead?

Comment: Also make sure your spelling is the same between the SQL and the parameter, unless you really _did_ name your parameter `variable`.

Comment: Yes it returns the correct value of 7 in this case

Comment: Slight side track...since you are not using stored procedures you might want to read this using AddWithValue. It will sometimes get the datatype wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I am using `.Parameters.Add("@variable", SqlDbType.Int).Value` updated question code to match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line

```
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(MySqlCommand.CommandText, conn.ConnectionString)
```

... you are passing in the CommandText and not the object "MySqlCommand"

The `SqlDataAdapter` has a constructor taking a command object as well as one taking a string...

Comment: The constructor you mention does not also take a connection string though? Is it a case of adding that separately? You can only pass the connection string in to the adapter while using Command.CommandText

Comment: @user2874417 Your string doesn't include the parameters you added.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes it does. `WHERE [My Id] = @variable` ...... `Parameters.Add("@variable")`

Comment: @Shnugo If I use the constructor that takes the command but NOT the connection string I am given the error: 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.'

Comment: @user2874417 Your object "MySqlCommand" has the parameter correctly defined. But when you open your adapter, you use only the CommandText, the parameters remain unused. instantiate your command with the connection and use the object to instantiate the adapter. Think about where and how (and if!!!) you use "MySqlCommand" and "commandBuilder"

Comment: Thats the one! Thank you. I added a line above the Adapter creation line `MySqlCommand.Connection = MyConnection` and passed the command as a parameter as a whole.